# Problema con conversion de string a date PHP

Tags: php, date

Tengo un problema, no soy muy habil con formatos de fecha, asi que pido ayuda rapido jaja.

Tengo un string, donde se ha obtenido una fecha, el problema es el formato.

```
$fecha = '16122020';
```

Y tengo problemas con darle formato, para usarlo en in `INSERT` a `mysql`.

```
$fecha = '16122020';
echo $fecha."</br>";
$ffecha = strtotime(date($fecha));
echo var_dump($ffecha);
Output: (bool)false
```

La idea es que ese formato de fecha, quede válido para poder insertarlo a MYSQL mas tarde.
De ante mano gracias !

Comment: En MySQL ¿qué formato espera que la fecha tenga?

Comment: Da igual, solo busco uno correcto, pero de preferencia `'Y-m-d'`

Comment: Nop... `string(10) "1970-07-06"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) de la clase [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) mismo a través del cual:

- Le pasamos 2 valores, el primero es el formato actual que tiene y el segundo es la variable que contiene esa *fecha* a formatear.
- Posterior, podemos usar el método `format` para indicar la salida esperada.

  ```
  $fecha = '16122020';

  $nuevaFecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('jmY', $fecha);

  echo $nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d');
  ```

Dando como salida:

> 2020-12-16

Considera que tanto el formato con el que la fecha actual esta como aquel con el que quieres que se muestre como resultado final depende de los [parámetros siguientes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters)

Comment: Perfecto! siento que anteriormente me sugirieron ese mismo método, pero no pude encontrarlo.

Comment: @Excorpion ahora que lo mencionas pienso que si (*y creo que también fui yo*), bueno ya que se quede esta publicación :)