# Especificación de uso de DateTime::createFromFormat en PHP para cadenas numéricas sin separadores

Tags: php, date, date-format

Hace algunos días vi la siguiente pregunta: [Problema con conversion de string a date PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415316/problema-con-conversion-de-string-a-date-php) formulada por [@excorpion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/131662/excorpion); en la que plantea la necesidad de **pasar de un formato de cadenas continuas a un formato de cadenas con separadores que pueda ser entendido por MySql**

```
<?php
    function transformacion($fecha){
        // hacer algo para formatear
        return $salida;
    }
    $fecha = '16122020';
    $transformada = transformacion($fecha);
    echo $transformada;
    // imprime en salida 16-12-2020
?>
```

a la que [@BetaM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/128299/betam) ofreció una excelente respuesta **en la que incluye una referencia a la [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters) en español**.
La solución ofrecida era simple y elegante:

```
<?php
    $fecha = '16122020';
    $nuevaFecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('jmY', $fecha);
    echo $nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Me pareció muy interesante porque la experiencia asociada a mis necesidades personales no incluía aplicar ese mecanismo de trasformación.
Inmediatamente leí la documentación del método y prepare un pequeño entorno de pruebas con la mente puesta en un detalle que, aunque no es evidente, no dejaba de suscitar inquietud:

> las cadenas continuas hacen posible escribir **fechas ambiguas** como 1111984
> ¿va a protestar el método createFromFormat? o, si no protesta
> ¿Como las va a interpretar.

Antes de probar releo la documentación para estar seguro de que el formato ambiguo no está prohibido. Y, me encuentro con que **en principio no hay una restricción explícita**. La documentación dice:

> **Día**
> d y j     Día del mes, 2 dígitos con o sin ceros iniciales    **01 a 31 o 1 a 31**
> **Mes**
> m y n     Representación numérica de un mes, con o sin ceros iniciales    01 hasta 12 o 1 hasta 12.

De modo que las fechas ambiguas son aceptadas. Inmediatamente procedo a construir un método que formatee fechas provenientes de cadenas continuas, sin restricciones, usando la solución propuesta por @BetaM, que usa la sintaxis válida indicada en dicha documentación:

```
<?php
/**
 * Prepara una cadena de fecha con formado día-mes-año
 * creada a partir de una cadena de fecha numérica continua del tipo diamesaño
 * Y devuelve un array de pares clave valor con la entrada recibida y la cadena
 * formateada para facilitar compararlas
 */
function test_formatearfecha(){
    //No pide explícitamente argumentos, acepta cualquier cantidad y sólo 
    //verifica que el primero sea un valor escalar, cadena o número
    //(de momento no interesa ser riguroso con los parámetros)
    //En caso de que el parámetro no sea como se espera o no esté
    //asigna una fecha ambigua como default (ya que es lo que quiero validar)
    $argumentos = func_get_args();
    $entrada = (isset($argumentos[0]) && is_scalar($argumentos[0]) ) 
             ? trim( '' . $argumentos[0]) : '1112000';
    $nuevaFecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('jmY', $entrada);
    $salida = [
        'Entrada'=>$entrada,
        'Fecha formateada'=>$nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d')
    ];
    return $salida;
}
```

Acto seguido ejecuto el método de prueba sin pasar parámetros para que tome la fecha ambigua que asigna como entrada por defecto.
En principio, espero que devuelva algo como 1 de noviembre de 2000 u 11 de enero de 2000 y para mi sorpresa devuelve 11 de noviembre del 0000. Ilustro con una imagen del volcado de ejecución en mi entorno de prueba:
[image: Imagen del volcado de ejecución]
y, como se puede ver en el volcado agrega un cero adicional al año. Supongo que como prefijo. Así que ejecuto nuevamente, usando un año razonable que me permita validar esa hipótesis: ejecuto

```
test_formatearfecha('1111984');
```

y, verifico que evidentemente agrega el cero como prefijo para el año:
[image: prueba con año sin ceros]
y la respuesta, aunque no cae en uno de los valores esperados deja dudas ¿Qué pasa si tanto día como mes son no ambiguos pero tienen un dígito? Ejecuto para 8 de agosto de 1984: **881984**

```
test_formatearfecha('881984');
```

y obtengo algo que no puedo interpretar a primera vista:
[image: Prueba con fecha no ambigua]
Transformó el día 88 en 26 (posiblemente de marzo) y luego movió el 19 hasta septiembre del año siguiente y quizá paso el año de 84 a 85.

De modo que aunque no lo diga explícitamente, el formato para fechas continuas **no es elástico** como se interpreta al leer la documentación.

**¿Cual sería la solución recomendada?**

Comment: Mi +1 tanto en la pregunta cómo en la respuesta, sabía que tu aporte sería de mucha calidad y aporta conocimiento a la comunidad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Respondo a mi propia pregunta, porque la respuesta es en cierto sentido evidente luego de ver los volcados de ejecución para los casos citados en la pregunta:

Cuando no se usan separadores explícitos (-, /,  , etc) las cadenas numéricas para representar fechas **deben tener exactamente dos dígitos para el mes y dos para el día**. Y, en caso de que la cadena inicie con el año debe tener 4 dígitos para representarlo.

**Adendum**
Es posible hacer **aritmética de fechas** y pasar sumas sobre la cantidad de días o de meses a la función DateTime::createFromFormat para obtener fechas futuras arbitrarias, por ejemplo ¿que fecha será dentro de 46 días y 3 meses, siendo hoy 21, 12 de 2020?
Sumo 46 a 21 y 3 a 12 y ejecuto la función para 67152020

```
<?php 
function test_formatearfecha(){
    $argumentos = func_get_args();
    $entrada = (isset($argumentos[0]) && is_scalar($argumentos[0]) ) 
             ? trim( '' . $argumentos[0]) : '1112000';
    $nuevaFecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('jmY', $entrada);
    $salida = [
        'Entrada'=>$entrada,
        'Fecha formateada'=>$nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d')
    ];
    return $salida;
}
// ejecuto el método y lo vuelco a pantalla (con un método personal de volcado
// equivalente a var_dump() pero con salida bonita )
dump_eh( test_formatearfecha('67152020') ); 
?>
```

Y el método **devuelve el cálculo de la fecha correcta**:
[image: Volcado de fecha más allá de los límites]
Luego, El método ***DateTime::createFromFormat* admite valores numéricos entre 00 y 99 tanto para el día como para el mes** haciendo posible una aritmética de fechas en ese rango.